# Vuejs get $refs value in methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple rows and I wish to get input value inside my tr refs but it returns undefined.

[image: one]

## Code

`Component`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Serial Number</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Product</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
            <td width="50"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index) in serial_numbers" :key="index">
            <td>
                <el-input ref="barcoded" v-model="row.barcode_id"></el-input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <el-input ref="product" v-model="row.product"></el-input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <el-input ref="amount" v-model="row.amount"></el-input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <el-input ref="price" v-model="row.price" readonly></el-input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <el-link v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove</el-link>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <el-button type="primary" class="button btn-primary" round @click="addRow">Add row</el-button>
</div>
```

`Script`

```
methods: {
    focusInput() {
        this.$refs.barcode_id.focus();
    },
    addRow() {
        var barcodes = document.createElement('tr');
        this.serial_numbers.push({
            barcode_id: '',
            product: '',
            amount: '',
            price: ''
        });

        // try to get value of barcode input
        console.log(this.refs.barcoded); // undefined

        this.$nextTick(function () { 
            const nbBarcodes = this.$refs.barcoded.length;
            this.$refs.barcoded[nbBarcodes - 1].focus(); 
        });
    },
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/7qL4gfu0/2/)

Comment: You are logging `refs` instead of `$refs`

Comment: @palaѕн here you go https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/7qL4gfu0/2/

Comment: @AlbertoRivera yes that was right, but still, how do i get input value?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `$refs` to get the value of an input? The input is bound using `v-model` to some data, so why not just read the values you want from that data?

Comment: @skirtle because i don't have access to `row.barcode_id` in `addRow` function. and the `barcode_id` will be accessible when i trigger submit button till then i actually can't have value in my model binding.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera what happend?! why you removed it?

Comment: I think my answer is not good. If it gets downvoted, I will remove it, as I think it may not follow the correct vue approach, even if it's functional, so others should not imitate it. I think the correct way to solve your problem is through v-model, as the other commenter said.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera well then do you have any solution on `v-model` approach? due to my explanations about it in this specific case?

Comment: @mafortis  Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the serial_numbers object instead of refs

```
console.log(this.serial_numbers[this.serial_numbers.length - 1]);

// this was moved from above
this.serial_numbers.push({
            barcode_id: '',
            product: '',
            amount: '',
            price: ''
        });
```

You should push the new element after retrieving the values you need

https://codepen.io/albertor24/pen/wvKYxOg

Comment: it needs little bit justify, see what i'm looking for is just to get input value of row before latest one (because latest one is just added and it's empty). here i explained it on screenshot based on your code https://ibb.co/JcBm8Gt